# Google AppEngine Flex: Building and pushing image for service failed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to a Rails 6 application to Google AppEngine flex. I've followed the steps [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-ruby-on-rails/index.html#0) and currently have the following `app.yaml` setup in my root:

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rails s --port $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby
env_variables: ...
```

When running `gcloud --project [PROJECT_ID] app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug` it continues until this point:

```
...
INFO: Need Dockerfile to be generated for runtime ruby
Building and pushing image for service [default]
```

At this point it's spinning up the following process on my machine:

```
python2 -S /usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py --project [PROJECT_ID] app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug
```

which uses 100% CPU and can run for 30min+ without anything happening. I also checked the network traffic at this point and there is nothing related to that process happening.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix it are very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you deploying from cloudshell or from your local computer with the cloud SDK?

Comment: @JoséSoní Deploying from my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04LTS) using Google Cloud SDK

Answer (score 0):

In the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/quickstart) the `app.yaml` file is in a different order, starting with the runtime and specifying the resources will have the machine.

The conbination of this two gives the dockerfile so the issue seems to be related to this file, I am adding a full working one.

```
runtime: ruby
env: flex
entrypoint: bundle exec ruby app.rb

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I tested with this one myself deploying from an Ubuntu 20.04 computer with the Cloud SDK 299 and worked fine.